# how to send form data with fileupload image in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send form data with attachment to php via ajax.

My code is :

```
var company_name = $('#companyname').val();
    var company_type = $('#companytype').val();
    var industry_sector = $('#industrysector').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
    var logo = $("#logo").prop("files")[0];
    var company_description = $('#company_description').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var rePassword = $('#rePassword').val();

    var data = {
        company_name: company_name,
        company_type: company_type,
        industry_sector: industry_sector,
        email: email,
        mobile: mobile,
        logo: logo,
        company_description: company_description,
        password: password
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {companyregister: data},
        url: "ajax/loginvia.php",
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend:function(){

        },
```

i am getting empty data to php controller. i tried in many ways, im unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With simple ajax it is some complex to perform you can use ajaxForm for this. It is easy to implement. Here is plugin url : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

It is so easy to implement have a look at this.

```
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
    type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
    data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
    contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
    cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
    processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
    success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
    {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $("#message").html(data);
    }
    });



$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
```